# Misner space - closed timelike curves

Tags: general-relativity, relativity, closed-timelike-curve

Could someone give me a good resource to read about closed timelike curves in [Misner space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misner_space)? Somewhere where they are actually derived and some comments are made for the simple 2D Misner space?

Comment: You could start with lecture by K. Thorne: http://inspirehep.net/record/348406/

Comment: Seen this, I want explicitly Misner space!

Comment: Explicitly Misner space serves as an explicit example in this lecture. If you still have  questions after working through the lecture, maybe you should ask a more specific question.

Comment: I have asked in the question, " Somewhere where they actually derived. ..."

Comment: What do you mean by “derived”? When you identify a point $A$ of Minkowski space with another point $A'$ that is in the absolute past of $A$, then any timelike curve from $A'$ to $A$ becomes a CTC. What else do you need?

Comment: The explicit math explaining that? Calculating the actual closed geodesic..?